# O que significa essa linha de código em Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Boa noite

Queria saber o que significa essa linha de código em Flutter / Dart:

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

o que significa o '=>' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É uma sintaxe conhecida como *fat arrow* ou simplesmente *arrow*.
Nada mais é do que um atalho para escrita de funções que só possuem uma *expression*.

Sendo assim, o seu exemplo:

```dart
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());
```

Serve como um atalho para:

```dart
void main() {
  return runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Note como ele substitui os `{}` e o `return`. Se sua função `main` executasse algo além de `runApp(const MyApp());` (tivesse mais de uma linha) ela não poderia ser transformada em *fat arrow*:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
  algumOutroMetodo();
}
```

Qualquer *expression* pode ser utilizada em uma função *fat arrow*. Exemplos:

```dart
int resposta() => 42;
int resposta() {
  return 42;
}


String hello() => 'Olá';
String hello() {
  return 'Olá';
}

bool maiorIdade() => idade > 18;
bool maiorIdade() {
  return idade > 18;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, ficou muito bem explicado!